# ATG AngularJs, Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet, atg-dust

I am Very beginner in ATG and Spring, I have done UI in AngularJs.
is it possible to use AngularJs for Oracle ATG web commerce? And how can I use spring in between to give http request to AngularJs? and is there any guide for these?.

I was not able to work from local host as my work location is in Local system and ATG installed in server,

From where can I get complete spring supported ATG .Jar files for web functionality development
Please give a clear picture about ATG and available codes with good references.
Please Advise.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do some research before posting so you can ask better questions.

Comment: (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGProgGuide/html/s0212nucleusresolverutil01.html)  go through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Spring` in order to have `AngularJS` read the `HttpRequests` from ATG. In fact it will probably complicate things if you try to do so.

What you should do is enable the [ATG Web Services Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0101particreatingandusingwebservices01.html). This will allow you to expose all the important functions in ATG as [RESTful Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1301usingrestwebservices01.html). Once you've done that you can use `AngularJS` to [interact with ATG](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11).

Comment: Thanks :) , I have starting problem with the same. ATG already has all the functionality (eg: login, registeration,cartItem, etc..) and I can easly send and receive data  from my angularjs, Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Correct. ATG already exposes functionality via RESTful services, you just need to enable it, as described in the documentation. Once you've enabled the services you can use AngularJS to interact with these services.

Comment: As I am very beginner I am facing difficulty, Can you please guide me through some documents where I can get good Idea?, I have gone through the Oracle documentation but its too confusing and could not get a solution.

Comment: FYI: I have Installed Fresh ATG and I have all the angularjs UI build For it.

Comment: Are you using the ATG Commerce Reference Store? Its setup process is documented. Once you've configured that you need to enable the RESTful APIs using the documentation links provided above.

Comment: Yes I am using ATG commerce Reference store.